# xcode 3.1.3 thread_start error

Tags: multithreading, xcode, exc-bad-access

I am currently working on an iPhone game and about 3 weeks ago I started receiving these strange errors that all originated from `thread_start` in the call stack. The weird thing is that the errors have been appearing on and off, and only recently have they reappeared after about a week. They also seem more likely to appear on the device than on the simulator. One of the errors that I received today was an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in `szone_free` on the simulator, but after rebuilding my project and running the app ran fine, although it still crashed on the device. Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: I'm getting something in this ballpark - did you gain any insight into this that you could share? Tx!